# Best way of implementing this in java

Tags: java, implementation

So I have this requirments:

- A class called Destination
- A HashMap called Destinations

The Destination class has an array of objects of the type Door. So basically I read a "door" from a file, and every door has an attribute "destination" which tells me which destination it belongs to.

**My question is, what's better?:**

a) A method in the object that holds Destinations that checks whether the destination for the new door exists or not in the HashMap Destinations, and therefore insert that door to its existing Destination or create the new Destination and then insert the door.

b) Override (?) the add method for the Destinations HashMap and implement the previous described functionality there.

c) Another way.

Thank you.

Comment: What the HashMap maps ? A Door to a Destination ?

Comment: I didn't understand your first question ("What the HashMap maps?"?), a Door is a door to a Destination and then the collection of all the Destinations are stored in the HashMap Destinations.

Comment: A HashMap is a object that maps keys to values. So maybe you are thinking about using a List or a Set instead of a Map to save all Destinations

Comment: Oh, thanks for the suggestion but I am using hashmaps because the destinations are always pulled back by its ID (this is part of a bigger system), so a HashMap is faster, I map the ID and the object (the list of destinations is fixed so I don't have to worry about the insertion time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java and similar languages we are more likely to create classes with meaningful names for our application than we are to have simple lists and maps and sets (as you would do in more dynamic languages).  What you will almost never see is someone subclassing HashMap or ArrayList or HashSet and overriding their add or put methods.

The most "Java-esque" approach would be to define a class called `Destinations` which can *contain* (as a field) a hash map of destination objects, indexed by id.  You then will create only those methods that make sense to your application, like

```
add(door, destination)
```

which can encapsulate your game logic.  No one needs to know there is a map (or list or set) behind the scenes.  To expose the map would mean your application had a leaky abstraction, which you will want to avoid.

Perhaps even better: It is also possible that what works best for you is to only have

```
class Door
```

and

```
class Destination
```

and make the map of all destinations be a field of Destination.  Without knowing more of what you are trying to do, it's hard to say.  Minimizing the number of classes seems like a good idea.  Can you encapsulate your map into Destination, and make static methods to access all doors?

Now if you decide to make a separate Destinations class, you would encapsulate your map like so:

```
class Destinations {
    private static Map<Integer, Destination> map = ...

    public static void add(Door door, Destination destination) ...
}
```

to make the call look like:

```
Destinations.add(door, destination);
```

Alternatively, your destinations map can be a singleton.  It's always fun to get opinions on the singleton vs. utility class question.  See what works best for your application.

TL;DR: Hide the map inside of another class so clients don't know there's a `java.util.HashMap` using either:

- a utility class `Destinations` with static methods
- a singleton class `DestinationInfo`
- the map hidden as a static field (with static methods) inside the model object `Destination` itself.

Comment: Thank you for the time you took to write this answer, I will look singleton in Google to know what works best. If singleton does not work for me, for sure I will took the alternative you described (for some reason creating a class Destinations seemed odd for me).

But any way thank you again.

Comment: I just read your edit, and I feel more comfortable with the Destinations class, looks more logical to me than mix functionality from a single Destination object with the set of Destinations. But I don't know, perhaps somebody else has an opinion on this issue?

Comment: It would be nice to get other opinions indeed.  The utility class Destinations is kind of nice because it keeps the Destination class itself more of a lightweight POJO, and separates game-global stuff out of the model object.  It's a tradeoff: lighther, simpler model objects versus more classes. :)  Perhaps codereview.stackexchange.com or programmers.stackexchange.com might be good venues for soliciting more opinions if no one else chimes in here.